# React-native vector and icons Installation Error

Tags: android, react-native

installing the package will remove the previously installed react-native-cli package.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This an issue with npm. You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379).

I suggest you to use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) or a more stable version of npm. Yarn is more easy to use with react-native since it even links the library after the instillation.

To solve the current problem, remove `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and if there is `yarn.lock` file. Then run the command `yarn` if you are using yarn or `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks friends. Solved problem

Answer (score 0):

If the 'react-native' module has version 0.4 and up, than you should update the 'react-native-vector-icons' module version to 4.0.
You can update using the following command

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons@4.0
```